# WebSphera /ibm_security_logout has not been defined

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7

Using WebSphera 7.0.0.19.
To logout  user from application page after some idle time  use this constaction:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900; URL=/ibm_security_logout?logoutExitPage=/Application" />
```

After 900 seconds get error:
SRVE0255E A WebGroup/VirtualHost to handle /ibm_security_logout has not been defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script **ibm_security_logout** may be accessible not by global path, but by local.
Parameter **logoutExitPage** must be relative to script **ibm_security_logout** location.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900; URL=/Application/ibm_security_logout?logoutExitPage=/" />
```

Mentioned way will logout user and redirect him to **/Application**